# Eclipse - Failed/Stop TestNG test causes compilation errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compiler-errors, testng

My project is a maven project, 
I'm running TestNG test on Eclipse while having (unintentionally) compilation error.

When test fails (on compilation) **all** classes failed to compile due to missing (basic) imports

I **must clean** project to resume old state

Same happens when I stop test in the middle, classes aren't compiled properly

Can this issues be avoided?

**EDIT**

I also can't run test while build project (it uses same compile files)

**EDIT 2**

Also happens when changing code during clean install

Comment: Yeah very simple fix your compile error ...?

Comment: @khmarbaise after test fails all classes are not compiling. I'm asking when failed to fix compilation before test execution

Comment: So without the project nor the exact error message nor the code it's impossible to help...

Comment: @khmarbaise simulating compilation error is simple as adding `}` to class